# How to add a custom semaphore to the linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

Basically I want implement my own semaphore inside the linux kernel and be able to use it in user programs.

I've made some progress implementing the kernel code however I do not know how to make semaphore type and the functions I've written available to user programs.

User programs would need to have access to my semaphore type and its functions (wait, signal, ...)

Is there any way to this so that a linux using a kernel compiled with my code would be able to use my semaphore simply by including a header file?

I'm no pro when it comes to the linux kernel, so if I'm making any obvious mistakes feel free to point them out.Thanks.
The kernel version I'm using is 2.6.32.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into the user space libraries for how a semaphore implemented for user space programs.

Semaphores are only available in kernels older 2.6.16 kernels, as mutex's appeared after that version of the kernel. Only the previous implementation used semaphores. The newer code should use mutexes instead which are used only in process context. You may want to look the following headers, struct's and api's.

```
#include <linux/mutex.h>
struct mutex
mutex_{lock,trylock,unlock,lock_interruptable}()
```

Also you may want to look [semaphore.c](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/kernel/semaphore.c) for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, I used semaphore.c as a guideline for my own semaphore. I tried looking through the posix semaphore.h file, it was a bit too complicated fir me but I guess I could go through them again.